# Refreshing view on change of data from backend - Angular 11

Tags: angular

I have a function that calls API, the response of API is changing every hour. My requirement is without refreshing page, API should be called only when there is change from backend, I used changedetection angular but not working. Here is the code below.

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ref.markForCheck();
    this.asyncCall();
  }
  asyncCall(){
    // calling API
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also have the server send you the data without explicitly requesting it. Check out [server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) or [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebSockets).

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to use setInterval to trigger an api call every hour, if i were you i would use this instead of having to manage server side events or sockets, because you'll have some work to do on serverside.